# How to avoid duplicate code in business logic classes above ef?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, interface, abstract-class

I have a business logic layer in my application that incapsulates work with EF.

I have tons of service classes that provide access to database and have similar methods so I want to avoid duplication.

### First example:

`xData` classes are DTO classes for `x` class generated by EF.

```
public class UserService
{
    public static bool Any()
    {
         // default logic
    }
    public static List<UserData> Filter(Expression<Func<UserData, bool>> predicate)
    {
         // default logic
    }
    public static long CreateOrUpdate(UserData userData)
    {
        // default method with custom logic
    }
    public static bool AuthorizeUser(UserData data)
    {
        // custom method
    }
}

public class BookService
{
    public static bool Any()
    {
         // default logic
    }
    public static List<BookData> Filter(Expression<Func<BookData, bool>> predicate)
    {
         // default logic
    }
    public static long CreateOrUpdate(BookData userData)
    {
         // default logic
    }
}
```

Main issue: *duplicated logic* in most of methods with only difference in types.

### Second example:

I've created a generic service that contains all of shared logic.

```
public abstract class Service<TEntity,TData> where TEntity : class
                                             where TData : IDataObject<TEntity>, new()
{
    public static bool Any()
    {
         // default logic
    }

    public static List<TData> Filter(Expression<Func<TData, bool>> predicate)
    {
         // default logic
    }

    public static long CreateOrUpdate(TData data)
    {
         // default logic
    }
 }
```

So my custom services now look like this:

```
public class UserService : Service<user, UserData>
{
     public new static long CreateOrUpdate(UserData userData)
     {
          // overriden custom logic
     }

     public static AuthorizeUser(UserData userData)
     {
          // custom method
     }

}


public class BookService : Service<book, BookData>
{
}
```

And now everything looks fine, but after that all my projects working with business logic layer need a reference to data layer because they don't know about data types e.g. when I try to use `BookService.Any();` I get an error that book class is undefined, missing reference.

I don't wanna add references to data layer in all my client project, so how to deal with it?

Comment: You should place all your entity classes in to a separate Domain project and reference that instead

Comment: @AmanB  entity classes are in separate project already, I don’t wanna reference that separate project, I wanna reference only business logic layer in client projects

Comment: Are you looking for Repository Patern? https://www.infoworld.com/article/3107186/application-development/how-to-implement-the-repository-design-pattern-in-c.html

Comment: @Bobo I don't need repository pattern here, EF gives enough abstraction with dbcontext and dbsets

Answer (score 0):

You could create a separate interface like `IService<TData>` which would the `Service<TEntity,TData>` type implement. Then you could utilize dependency injection and just provide the concrete `BookService` type as the implementation of `IService<BookData>`. This way you don't have to reference the concrete `Book` entity in your top layers at all and can simply work with `BookData`.